# How to add Widgets to GridLayout dynamically,how to make tableviewer resizable

Tags: eclipse, layout, tableviewer

I am using a Gridlayout like screenshot

Tableviewer1 , TableViewer2, Button

My Question is

how to add text and label dynamically when user clicking Button?

How to make TableViewer resizable?[image]

Comment: Resize the table under what circumstances? Do you have a fixed number of labels you want to show or does it vary a lot?

Comment: 1)resize tableviewer means if i use mouse to drop table border , then i can resize it.

Comment: You would probably use a `SashForm` for resizing by drag,

Comment: the numbers and contents of label will vary, but i will get those information when clicking Button. then i need insert them between TableViewer1 and TableViewer2

Answer (score 1):

If you want to resize parts by dragging use a `SashForm` control to divide up the part in to two or more sections. You can then drag the sashes to resize.

If you have a limited number of controls you wish to show or hide you can use the `exclude` member of `GridData` and the control `setVisible` method:

```java
GridData data = new GridData(.... )
data.exclude = true;
control.setLayoutData(data);
control.setVisible(false);
```

Reverse the `exclude` and `setVisible` settings to show the control. You will need to call `layout(true)` on the parent `Composite` to redo the layout.

You can also just create new controls as required in the `Composite`, again calling `layout(true)` on the composite.